# Complex Category Setup // Looking for Best Practices

Tags: matrix, playa, categories, structure

Okay so I have looked at [How to create a complex stockist list using Structure and/or categories](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/291/how-to-create-a-complex-stockist-list-using-structure-and-or-categories) and have studied all of the comments carefully but I don't think any of those setups are going to work for me. Although I'm open to any ideas on how to implement those into what I'm doing.

Okay here's my scenario and setup:

- Businesses Channel
- State and City Channels as sub-pages with Structure

I have a matrix field setup for each individual business with Playa fields pulling in the State and City.

I have a small set of Categories associated with each individual Business.

What I would like to do is to have a list of States on a Business page (I currently have this setup which pulls a list of each State in the "State" channel". that clicks through to the list of City's under each State.

I figured I would need a relationship (Playa) for each City, so EE knows which State each belongs too. I have this portion setup too.

**WHERE MY PROBLEM LIES**

I'm not sure how I am going to pull in (for example) *Bob's Towing company in Boulder, CO* on the business page.

I think using Playa is the way to go, but I'm currently lost at the moment on how to bring it all together. I want to avoid having to setup more Structure pages under each and every City as this will quickly become quite the mess.

I am open to virtually anything.

**WHAT I'M GOING FOR**

1. Business Page
2. Listings of States on Business Page
3. Listings of Cities from the States page, making it easy for people to find what they are looking for
4. Have a list of Categories clicked from the States page with individual businesses organized accordingly.

I am certain there's a better way of doing this and am looking to the EE gods for help on this. I am open to setting up a Channel for each State if need be, but again I'm looking for some better suggestions.

Thanks again for reading this and offering any advice on how I can bring all of this together!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just simply put your State/City structure in as categories/subcategories? You can use any number of add-ons to pull out just children and Low's Seg2Cat to get rid of the /category/ keyword etc, but seems like a case for categories to me.

Comment: The problem is that I want to keep as much of the URL structure together as possible: domain.com/businesses/colorado/boulder etc... I'll need these as pages for SEO and organizational purposes. I don't mind domain.com/businesses/colorado//bobs-towing versus domain.com/businesses/colorado/boulder/local/bobs-towing Just not sure how else to keep the URLs in play as much as possible.

Comment: How would I then account for Businesses that fit into more than one category? Some businesses will also be in different cities and states, which in your setup would work just fine. But I was thinking that having a Channel for State and a Channel for City would allow me to keep URLs intact. Then I would just select one or more categories for each business while also having everything organized based on the categories.

Comment: OK - how about one channel for businesses. One category group for category. One category group for state/city. And some query help: http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials/comments/simple-multifaceted-navigation-using-categories

Low Seg2Cat will get you those URLs.

Comment: Hmmm that might work but I still see an issue with adding content, meta data and more to those category pages. I'm not sure how I can tackle this without have some pages involved. Thoughts?

Comment: Depends on how complex the content is - you do have category fields (and custom fields) to work with.

Comment: Okay I think your sample will mostly work. But how would you work in nested Cities into the parent Category of State? I just need one level and sadly am not much of a SQL programmer. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry Mark - it was meant to be a 'think about this direction" rather than 'here is the total answer'.  I didn't do another level down so it would require a chunk of time to think about and experiment with.

Comment: Gotcha. Something for me to look into. I think that this approach will work although the Category setup is a bit clunky. I liked using Playa for the Cities and States and having those in a Matrix field, was just much cleaner, but I didn't like having to setup individual pages and all of those Channels for each state as I was going about it before. Thanks Boyink for the help!